# Cannot answer questions or add comments

Tags: support, comments, answers

Why can't I answer questions or add comments to any of mine or other's Stack Overflow posts?

I am using Chrome web browser and Windows 8. I am seeing the following errors in browser developer tool:

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined`
- `Failed to load resource`

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? What happens when you try? If you open the browser developer tools, do you see any errors?

Comment: As for adding comments on other peoples posts - you do not have [enough reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) (50) in order to do that.

Comment: This is the right location to ask for help with problems posting on Stack Overflow, but we need a little more information.

Comment: does looking here help at all: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans  -it might help explain why you cannot answer a question?

Comment: I am using chrome web browser and window 8 OS. I seeing the following errors in browser developer tool (Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined) and (Failed to load resource)

Comment: I would also like to ask, why I cannot accept answers from my posts? Is this feature disabled, when you account is banned. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Usually theres a time limit of about 10 or 8 minutes for people with a reputation under 10 as for banning im not sure

Comment: You seem to be on a network that is blocking our JavaScript - you need to talk to your network administrators to solve this issue.

Comment: To clarify - there are no bans on your account - not question bans, not answer bans and it is not suspended.

Comment: thanks you so much for the update and clarifying the issue.  I shall talk to my network admins associate regarding the javascript issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: To clarify - we are serving JavaScript both from the stackexchange/stackoverflow domains but also use the Google CDN to get jQuery - if ajax.googleapis.com is blocked, that's a problem on our sites.